# PyQt: отлавливание исключений в QThread потоках

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

Никак не могу сообразить, как можно отловить исключения в потоках `QThread`.
При возникновении исключения в потоке в консоль ничего не выводится. Приходится через `print` проходить подозрительные части кода в потоке, или делать глобальный `try / except` в потоке, чтобы по смыслу ошибки выявить её место.
Гугл ничего толкового на мои запросы не ответил (в крайнем случае на вопросы в моей формулировке). Уже примучился искать решение...
Может кто-нибудь подскажет технику отлова исключений в потоке.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это нормальное состояние дел в многих языках программирования, что Вы должны самостоятельно обрабатывать исключения в потоках. Глобальный `try..except` на поток - одно из решений.

Если Вам не нравиться это, создайте свой наследник QThread, который просто будет запускать поток в `try..except` и наследуйте все свои потоки от него.

```
class TryThread(QThread):

  def new_run(self):
    print("Abstract class")

  def run(self):
    try:
      self.new_run()
    except:
      print ("Ups")
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но как в такой конструкции получить такие ценные сведения как Traceback и соответствующие сведения о типе исключения, её строке и файле?

Comment: ответ [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564559/get-exception-description-and-stack-trace-which-caused-an-exception-all-as-a-st) - один модуль и пара строк.

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно!